# Write a function that removes any properties on the given object whose values are strings longer than the given number and returns the object

Tags: javascript, for-loop, object, if-statement, properties

I am writing a function to delete an object with values larger than a given number but everything I seem to be trying is not working.

```
function removeStringValuesLongerThan(num, obj) {
  for (let prop in obj) {
    if (obj[prop] > num) {
      delete obj[prop];
      }
      return obj;
    }
  }

let competitorDetails = {
  name: 'Montana Slim',
  age: 20,
  location: 'Texas'
}

removeStringValuesLongerThan(6, competitorDetails)
```

My code is returning:

{ name: 'Montana Slim', age: 20, location: 'Texas' }

Can anyone give me some hints as to where I am going wrong? I have looked at other similar questions on here but their answers are not helping me.

Comment: Position of ```return obj;``` statement is incorrect. You must place that statement outside the for loop.

Comment: This did not work. It is still returning the same output.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You are checking if the value of `obj[prop]` is greater than `num`.

What you should do is check if `obj[prop]` is a `string` and if `obj[prop].length` is greater than `num`.

Basically change this part:

```
if (obj[prop] > num) {
```

to:

```
if (typeof obj[prop] === 'string' && obj[prop].length > num) {
```

Comment: This worked I tried something similar using !isNaN but the typeof worked! thank you for your help!